# Why am I getting inflight/uncommitted errors?

Tags: ember.js

So, I've got a `createCharacter` method in my controller. It mostly works, but when I try populating a hasMany field in a `forEach`, I get an `attempted to handle event 'loadedData'...` error. One was saying the data was inflight. One was saying uncommitted (I tried doing `store.commit()`. That's when the error switched to inflight).

Here's the method in question. Nothing else should be editing or writing to or reading from these records (that I know of, at least):

```
createCharacter: function(){
  var character = App.Character.createRecord({
    isEditing: true,
    (...)
  });


    //Broken
    App.Skill.find().forEach(function(item, index){
        console.log(item.get('id'));
        var newSkill = character.get('skills').createRecord({
            rank: 0,
            skill: item
        });
        //newSkill.save();
    });

    /*//Works (but doesn't make all the records I need)
    character.get('skills').createRecord({
        rank: 0,
        skill: App.Skill.find(1)
    });
    */

    /*this part is because I can't figure out how to filter records from a hasMany property. Not entirely relevant to the aforementioned issue, but it has the same problem when it's uncommented.
            var skills = character.get('skills');
    var skillsList = App.Skill.find().getEach('id');
    $.each(skillsList, function(index, value){
        var rankID = skills.createRecord({
            rank: 0,
            skill: App.Skill.find(value),
        });
        switch(App.Skill.find(value).get('type')){
            case 1:
                character.get('generalSkills').addObject(rankID);
                break;
            case 2:
                character.get('combatSkills').addObject(rankID);
                break;  
            case 3:
                character.get('knowledgeSkills').addObject(rankID);
                break;
        }
    });*/
    character.save();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is your data coming from the backend or do you have fixtures?

Comment: For now, just fixtures. The next step is going to be just local storage data (that is, no fixtures or server data, just what the user enters). After that, I'll add a backend.

Comment: Wait, I'm dumb. There will still be some fixture data in the next version, then backend after that.